# How do you make a picture change as you scroll down a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this really cool effect on this page, scroll 2/3 down to see it It's a "pencil" image(multiple images from different angles) that change as you scroll down, it will do that same if you scroll up. link is here https://www.fiftythree.com/pencil

Anyway, can anyone tell me how i could implement that in my site? Or the name of the effect so i can look it up.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? No one is going to just come up with a solution for you without you showing some effort on your own.

Comment: Hi Mike. I don't even know where to start, just looking for pointers. What is this called? It's hard to look for it when i don't know what I'm looking for in precise terms.

Comment: There's no precise term for it. Learn how to rotate a picture. Then learn how to change something when the user scrolls. Combine the two and you've got a solution.

Comment: there is nothing to rotate, the img should just change, the title was wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three steps:

1. Listen to the scroll event.
2. Get the current scroll position.
3. Set the image source based on that position.

```js
var imageEl = document.getElementById('fake-image');

function getSrc(scrollPos) {
  if (scrollPos < 200) return 'image one.jpg';
  if (scrollPos < 300) return 'image two.jpg';
  if (scrollPos < 400) return 'image three.jpg';
  if (scrollPos < 500) return 'image four.jpg';
  if (scrollPos < 600) return 'image five.jpg';
  return 'image six.jpg';
  }

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  imageEl.textContent = getSrc(window.scrollY);
});
```

```css
#fake-image {
  background: aliceblue;
  height: 5000px;
  padding-top: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fake-image">
  Fake image
</div>
```

You'll probably want to pre-load the images or, as another answer said, use show/hide and have multiple images.

Comment: This is still pretty awesome. The OP shouldn't expect the full solution, but a general idea of how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by listening to the `scroll` event.

when this event triggers

1. calculate the position of the target div (image wrapper)
2. based on your logic, change the picture inside / or do nothing..

Answer (score 1):

You can right click the image in chrome and say "Inspect element" , you'll see that he has a bunch of images inside the container that are all hidden (except the first one, which is shown my default).

As you scroll down, you have a function that listens for the scroll event and the value of the scroll bar position.

Based on the value above, you can set the "active" class (which means show/hide in the portal you have linked to) to the corresponding image.

TL/DR : Have multiple images and show/hide them based on the scroll position by listening to the onscroll event.